# wordpress is reinstalling after putting database in wp-config.php

Tags: wordpress

I have lost files in file manager but have database of website with me. I tried to set wp-config.php and put old database details but it starts the wordpress installation process after connecting to database.

PS: I have theme files with me

Comment: shefali you dont needed any Wordpress secret keys etc, you just need to add database detail(bd name, dbuser, db password, host ) and table prefix  in wp-config.php

Comment: i did but still it takes me to installing new wordpress

Comment: What changes have you made to the wp-config.php file?

Comment: I have lost all files but have database & theme with me. I uploaded wordpress with theme and have put old database details in wp-config.php. So that it shows old pages back in website but it start reinstalling wordpress.

Comment: Probably what is happening is that the its not detecting the current wp install on your page. But again you need to specify, what changes have you made to any files/folders?

Comment: I fixed it now problem was i didnt add prefix which was used in older database. wordpress couldn't detect wp_ prefix in database.

Comment: table prefix this what i have mentioned in the 1st comment

Comment: I had put table prefix but it was wp_ and database had wpx_

Answer (score 1):

Prefix in database should be same what you have put when setting wp_config.php

for example if database has wpx_ prefix to table name then in wp_config.php change wp_ to wpx_

Comment: +1 Mostly when prefix is wrong can cause this issue. recheck your database connection configuration and prefix

Comment: Glad you have learned a new lesson and find out the answer yourself. If you have lost your files there is no point in keeping those data in the database.

Comment: I have theme and can install theme and connect with old database, now only thing which is missing is photos from old website. All pages and posts are working fine just no photos are there.